# The proper way to display multiple windows in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently working on a project using Python and tkinter.

The problem is that I don't know what's the proper way to display multiple windows, or screens, I don't know how to call them. Let me explain better.

When the application starts the login screen appears. After that, if I click register, I want to go to the register screen, but I don't want it to be a separate window (I don't want to have 2 windows displayed at the same time), but rather another window with different content ?!

How should I handle properly this situation? Create a second window using `Toplevel` and hiding the first (can I do that?) or changing the widgets of the first?

[Code I've written so far](https://github.com/drobert19/Compressed-Storage)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050

Comment: @BryanOakley, thank you! I think that this solution perfectly suits my needs

Answer (score 0):

You can do that- just call `window.withdraw()` on the `Toplevel` you need to hide after creating a new `Toplevel`. Changing the widgets in the first is also an option- if you like, you could always try a `Notebook` widget and disable manual flipping or just put each "screen" in a frame and `grid_` or `pack_forget` them to remove them from the window.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will go with maintaining one window containing more frames.